# How do I delete all versions of a nuget from a Azure DevOps Feed?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I know that I can delete a specific version of a nuget, but how do I delete all the versions of a nuget?
And even better is there a way to select multiple nuggets and delete all of them including all their versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete all versions from specific nuget if you are using the organization artifact repository. You need to select particular nuget, click on Versions tab, select all packages and then delete. Just important notice you cannot publish new packages with version used before even if the old package is deleted

Comment: Works! Is there also a way to delete multiple nugets (with all versions) at the same time?

Comment: at this point if you want to remove different nugets in bulk you can only delete the latest versions of those packages. Artifact Repo will take the previous version as latest after delete operation